# How to remove multiple elements from array using splits in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following array.

```
array =  ["5ms=208", "6ms=114", "7ms=95", "8ms=49", "9ms=38", "10ms=36",
          "11ms=35", "12ms=20", "13ms=24", "14ms=19", "15ms=15", "16ms=10", 
          "4550ms=0", "4600ms=0", "4650ms=0", "4700ms=0", "4750ms=0",
          "4800ms=0", "4850ms=0", "4900ms=0", "4950ms=0"]
```

For each element of the array, I wish to extract the string representation of a number following the equals sign, convert it to an integer and return the following array.

```
[208, 114, 95, 49, 38, 36, 35, 20, 24, 19, 15, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: That's not a valid ruby array.

Comment: I've made assumptions in my edit of your question (e.g., converting strings to integers). If I am in error, edit to correct, of course.

Comment: You can try this one  `array = array.map { |val| val[/\d*\z/].to_i }`

Comment: IMO,it is very much clear, and good question for beginner. That might not be valid array ,but is very much clear.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming those were actually strings, you could do this:

```
array = ["5ms=208", "6ms=114", "7ms=95", "8ms=49", "9ms=38", "10ms=36", "11ms=35"]
split = array.map { |time| time.split('=')[1] }
```

And the result will be:

```
["208", "114", "95", "49", "38", "36", "35"]
```

Comment: Similar solution: `array.map { |x| x.split('=').last.to_i }`

Answer (score 2):

```
array.map { |s| s[/(?<=\dms=)\d+\z/].to_i }
  #=> [208, 114, 95, 49, 38, 36, 35, 20, 24, 19, 15, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

`(?<=\dms=)` is a *positive lookbehind*, requiring the match to be immediatelly preceded by the string `"\dms="`, where `\d` is any digit. `\d\z` ensures that there are only digits in the remainder of the string (`\z` being the end-of-string anchor) in order for there to be a match.

Answer (score 1):

Given your array of Strings:

```
array = ["5ms=208", "6ms=114", "7ms=95", "8ms=49", "9ms=38", "10ms=36", "11ms=35", "12ms=20", "13ms=24", "14ms=19", "15ms=15", "16ms=10", "4550ms=0", "4600ms=0", "4650ms=0", "4700ms=0", "4750ms=0", "4800ms=0", "4850ms=0", "4900ms=0", "4950ms=0"]
```

this should do the job:

```
array.map { |element| element[/\d*\z/].to_i }
# Array of Integers
# => [208, 114, 95, 49, 38, 36, 35, 20, 24, 19, 15, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I hope you find that helpful.

Comment: Note my edit of the question.

Comment: I went for you suggestion and it worked perfectly! Thank you so much!!! You helped me optimize my time a whole lot better at work :D